# ecto How to modify update_at only when updating

Tags: elixir, ecto

When inserting data with a unique index, I just want to update the updated_at value, rather than id+1 how to do it?

```
Repo.insert_all(Ecto.module, all, on_conflict: :replace_all)
```

on_conflict: set
I don't know how to get the current time, 
Ecto.DateTime.utc is error

How do I write Repo.insert_all

schema(model)

```
defmodule Zerg.VContractVContractGroup do
  use Zerg.Web, :model

  schema "vcontracts_vcontract_groups" do
    belongs_to :vcontract, Zerg.VContract
    belongs_to :vcontract_group, Zerg.VContractGroup

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:vcontract_id, :vcontract_group_id])
    |> validate_required([:vcontract_id, :vcontract_group_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the schema (model) for better understanding

Comment: sorry, I think model is not necessary，but  add it  now.

Comment: you will have to find any other alternative to update_all, as per the documentation 3rd paragraph. 
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3

Comment: However, this is how i use update_all 
`Repo.insert_all(model,[[model_id: "aaaaa",state: c",inserted_at:Ecto.DateTime.utc,updated_at:Ecto.DateTime.utc],[model_id: "aaabb",state: "c",inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime.utc,updated_at:Ecto.DateTime.utc]])`